# Nativescript: Action bar background colour is not visible in iOS15

Tags: ios, iphone, nativescript, nativescript-plugin, ios15

I am working on a Nativecript(6.5.2) mobile application, it is working fine on both android and iOS devices, but the action bar background color is not visible on the iOS devices having version iOS 15. otherwise, the app is working absolutely fine.

I am not sure if ios have updated their UI policy or something else.
Below are the screenshots of both iOS 15 where the background colour of the action bar is not visible and another is iOS 14.2 where the background colour of the action bar is visible.

iOS 15

[image]

iOS 14.2

[image]

can anyone please help with this?

Answer (score 1):

As you have stated, the issue is to do with iOS 15.  For context, there is some [information about it here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682420).

If upgrading Nativescript is an option for you, then maybe give that a try as it seems [8.10](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/releases/tag/8.1.0-core) has support for this change.  Bear in mind though that there is some significant architecture change between 6.x and 8.x so be prepared to battle with any plugins you might have.

If, like myself, upgrading is not an option, you might be able to cherry pick some changes from the actionbar file (such as [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/9534/commits/c3f8570a3c84224ee7a510597c4a8c9e27c4e897) and [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/commit/7e35fdf143894f473a5140ceec4f26326164f393)) that may help.  The first change I can confirm restores the background colour, but leaves the title text black and the ActionBar links blue, which may not work with your colour scheme.  I'm hopeful the second link (which I am in the middle of testing) will restore text colour preferences.